# Hex string to number

Tags: hex

I am trying to reverse engineer a datalogger file (parker `.scpo` I believe).
I think it must be a 16bit format but I cant get the numbers to line up.
Data is stored in the form of a hex string I believe. First 100 characters here:

```
  BBFEBBFEBC09BC09BBFEBBFEBC09BC09BC09BC09BBE7BBFEBBFEBBFEBC09BBFEBC09BBFEBBFEBC15BBFEBBFEBBFEBBFEBBF2[continued...]
```

Luckily I also have an export of this particular file, the corresponding values are here:

```
0.036,0.036,0.04,0.04,0.036,0.036,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.04,0.027,0.036,0.036,0.036,0.04,0.036,0.04,0.036,0.036,0.045,0.036,0.036,0.036,0.036,0.031,0.031,0.027,0.013,-0.033,-0.028,0.004,0.013,0.018,0.031,0.027,0.04,0.059,0.059,0.068,0.073,0.054,0.045,0.04,0.036,0.027,0.027,0.036,0.031,0.031,0.022[continued...]
```

I also found the following metadata that I believe relates to this channel, last three entries are data series the first of which is above:

```
objVersion : 1
SMType : SMP
inputType : IN1
Priority : 1
ColorSerialized : 1
Name : ...
Sensor : eSCPT
Attention : 5
Alarm : 10
Scaling : eFS
LowerScaling : 0
UpperScaling : 0
Unit : bar
LowerRange : -1
UpperRange : 15
SignalUnit : V
LowerSignalRange : -0.2
UpperSignalRange : 3
CalcFormula : None
CAN_VID : None
CAN_REV : None
CAN_PCODE : None
CAN_SER : None
SlopeDin : eRising
LogicalDOUTOperation : e1A
DOUTTriggerA : eLevel
ConditionA : None
DOUTTriggerB : eLevel
ConditionB : None
SlopeDout : eRising


objVersion: 1
SMType: SMP
inputType: IN1
interval: 16
actValuesSerializedSMP: BBFEBBFEBC09BC09BBFEBBFEBC09BC09BC09BC09BBE7BBFEBBFEBBFEBC09BBFEBC09BBFEBBFEBC15BBFEBBFEBBFEBBFEBBF2[continued...]
minValuesSerializedSMP: BBDCBBD0BBE7BBDCBBE7BBDCBBDCBBE7BBE7BBF2BBE7BBE7BBE7BBDCBBFEBBF2BBFEBBF2BBF2BBF2BBFEBBE7BBF2BBE7BBE7[continued...]
maxValuesSerializedSMP: BC15BC09BC15BC09BC09BC15BC09BC15BC15BC09BC09BC20BC20BC15BC15BC20BC20BC20BC2CBC20BC20BC20BC15BC20BC09[continued...]
```

Somewhere it mentions 1 decimal place which made me think fixed point or `bcd`.

Does anyone recognize this encoding, are there any keywords that might help me in the right direction?
Are there any resources that I could look at that may help.
If there are any relevant tags please either add them or let me know.

Things I have already tried:

- Big and little endian floats and ints (16bit) ( `h`, `H`, `e` in python struct module)
- BCD ([from this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626800/2121419)) as well as reversed

Things that I have considered and not (completely) explored:

- Scaling the values but some of the range values in the header/metadata
- Some sort of operation using `LogicalDOUTOperation` from the metadata.
- What is SMP Encoding

Complete Data:

- [Encoded Values](https://pastebin.com/7xday1bf)
- [Actual Values](https://pastebin.com/wEDmWr9V)

First 20 points:

- [image: Encoded Values]
- [image: Actual Values]

Taking the encoded Value `X` and the actual value `Y`:
the following appears to hold: `AX+B = Y`  where `A` and `B` are `9/23000 = 0.00039130....` and `-18.79591...`

Comment: Can you control the values that are being encoded? Try encoding some powers of two that have a simple representation in binary. I tried both `bfloat16` and 'float16` - both don't apply on your data

Comment: @sudhackar Unfortunately no, we have some old datalogger files lying around, but do not regularly use this type of logger.

Comment: Please attach the complete series and I can do some exponent based analysis to rule out if the data is transformed in any way

Comment: In the current state of the values posted the hex values tend to increase linearly - `0.027 : BBE7, 0.031 : BBF2, 0.036 : BBFE, 0.040 : BC09, 0.045 : BBF2` Any more data will help me confirm more.

Comment: Thank you @Sudhacker, I have attached graph for first 20 points, and pastebins for a complete series.

Comment: It does look linear, but the scaling factors I got were not very nice or recognizeable numbers

Comment: Paste for encoded value get deleted repeatedly, not sure why

Comment: I don't have anything more enlightened than: `
    a = [0xBBE7, 0xBBF2, 0xBBFE, 0xBC09, 0xBC15]
    for v in a:
        print("%0.3f" % (0.0003913043 * v - 18.7964))
` ->  0.027   0.031  0.036  0.040   0.045